# Can I delete an HFONT object directly after using it to set the font of a control?

Tags: c, winapi

I am setting the font of a `"BUTTON"` control like this:

```
HFONT hFont = CreateFont(16, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Tahoma");
SendMessage(hButton1, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, TRUE);
```

Can I delete `hFont` directly after calling `SendMessage()`, or does `hButton1` needs to be destroyed first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632642.aspx):

> The application should call the `DeleteObject` function to delete the font when it is no longer needed; for example, **after it destroys the control**.

So you should destroy your control first.

Comment: [More details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/12/8945692.aspx#8948165)